# I am having problems with Pythons `subprocess.popen` hanging

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a simple function that calls the same `subprocess.popen` command on multiple items from a list. It executes the first 2 items in the list no problem, however the action on the third hangs.

It seems that the `process_null.communicate()` never executes or doesnt finish at least as I never get the output from the 3rd item in the list. I have tried changing the list, but get the same results. Any ideas to whats going on here?

```
def check_list(server_list):
    null_list = []

    for target in server_list:
        command_null="rpcclient -N -U '' {}". format (str(target))
        process_null = subprocess.Popen(command_null, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        output_null = process_null.communicate()[0].replace('\n','')

        if "NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED" in output_null or "NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED" in output_null or "NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL" in output_null:
            print '[-]  ' + target + '\tDenied NULL Session'
        else:
            print '[+]  ' + target + '\tAccepted NULL Session'
            null_list.append(target)


    return null_list
```

**Output**

```
[-]  192.168.1.3    Denied NULL Session
[-]  192.168.1.65   Denied NULL Session
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `rpcclient` successfully establishes a connection it starts a shell and waits for commands to be entered on `stdin` if none are given using the `-c` flag, which is what happens here. You don't see the prompt because you redirect all output (`stdout` + `stderr`) to a pipe, but you don't do the same for `stdin`, which means the input will be read from the same tty the python interpreter is running on.

Also, you shouldn't use `shell=True` with a string argument if not absolutely necessary, use a list of arguments instead:

```
command_null = ['rpcclient', '-N', '-U', '', str(target)]
```

To fix your problem you have two options:

- supply a command to execute when successfully connected:

  ```
  command_null = ['rpcclient', '-N', '-U', '', '-c', 'exit', str(target)]
  ```
- use `stdin=PIPE` when opening the process, which causes `rcpclient` to exit when `stdin` is closed by `communicate()`:

  ```
  process_null = subprocess.Popen(command_null, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
  ```

Comment: Apologies for the delay, although your answer fixes the issue im having it doesnt explain why it fails after 3 executions, but works for the previous 2. Thanks again for the input

Comment: It fails to create a connection for the first two servers, then succeeds to connect to the third, and only in that case it tries to read commands from stdin after a successful login. That's why you see 'denied' two times and then it hangs, it's the case when a connection can be established that causes problems.